# "Мне много не надо () власть над миром и чего-нибудь покушать"

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, двоеточие

Известная фраза: "Мне много не надо() власть над миром и чего-нибудь покушать" — написала и поняла, что не знаю, что поставить после "надо": тире или двоеточие?
Как вы думаете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Более всего уместно двоеточие. Бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть поясняет первую, раскрывает её смысл, можно вставить "а именно"

"Мне много не надо:(что именно надо?) власть над миром и чего-нибудь покушать"

Ставят и запятую, выделяя присоединительные отношения, даже добавляют "только": "Мне много не надо,только власть над миром и чего-нибудь покушать".

Видела и с точкой,оформлено как парцелляция: "Мне много не надо.Власть над миром и чего-нибудь покушать".Тоже экспрессивно.

И с тире видела. Тоже объяснимо: во второй части неожиданное "власть над миром", которое представляет собой как раз много.
Так что все знаки возможны, выбирайте, какой смысл вкладываете во фразу.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы двоеточие поставил.
Более всего напоминает перечисление.

Comment: Я бы тоже.

Comment: Аргументация та же? Потому как я допускаю и тире, тут можно ведь и по-другому трактовать...

Comment: Мне много не надо: (чего именно не надо?)власть над миром и чего-нибудь покушать.Я думаю, что это бессоюзное предложение, где вторая часть поясняет первую.

Comment: Здесь рассказывается, что надо, а не что не надо.

Comment: Спасибо, слишком быстро прочитала... Здесь неполнота вдобавок. Мне много не надо (а надо чего именно?):...